# Put values on a map with pre-given coordinates

Tags: r, mapping, visualization

I have the following data, it's forest fire data

```
X   Y   month   day temp    RH  wind    rain    area
7   4   oct     sat 14.6    33  1.3        0    0
8   6   mar     fri 8.3     97    4      0.2    0
8   6   mar     sun 11.4    99  1.8        0    0
8   6   aug     sun -0.2    29  5.4        0    0
```

These are the data meanings.

X - x-axis spatial coordinate within the Montesinho park map: 1 to 9

Y - y-axis spatial coordinate within the Montesinho park map: 2 to 9

- month - month of the year: \jan" to \dec"
- day - day of the week: \mon" to \sun"
- temp - temperature in degrees Celsius
- RH - relative humidity in %: 15.0 to 100
- wind - wind speed in km/h
- rain - outside rain in mm/m2
- area - the burned area of the forest (in ha)

[Something like the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUlec.png)

And I want to visualize the map with average burnt areas. I want it somehow alike to the image(I cannot embed because of low reputation). It is done by plotly, so it does not seen in pdf. But I need output in pdf. It can just be 2D something. Is it too hard code to write for a beginner? If not please provide me with some hints.

Answer (score 0):

This will plot the average burnt area by X and Y, but I'm not sure what you mean by "do a statistical description"

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  group_by(X, Y) %>% 
  summarise(AvgBurntArea = mean(area)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(X, Y)) + 
    geom_tile(aes(fill = AvgBurntArea))
```

Comment: it gives following error. 
Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

In fact I want I want something like the picture I added in the question. But I did it with plotly and it just does not show anything into pdf @Jordo82

Comment: I think you have a typo in the function; it's `group_by()` not `group_by_()`